# C# bitmap rows and columns help

Tags: c#, bitmap, grid, location, image

I want to have a bitmap or picture ( not sure ) of rows and columns such that say if i set 10 rows and 10 columns then it must build a class ( not sure ) with rows and columns with width 10 and height 10 such that i can access any location and set an image any where in that box/location how do i do it?
thanks a lot in advance

something like i pass

```
private printGrid(int x, int y) {
  // this function will print x rows and y columns such that each box's width is 10 px and height is 10px and also a way to modify any (x,y) in this to hold an image of 5px at later time
}

private insertImage(Image img, int x, int y) {
  // inserts the image in the xth row and yth column
}
```

how do i do it in C#?

Comment: Could you rephrase that please? I don't understand what you want to do...

Comment: what i want is a picture made dynamically such the it is divided into rows and columns with each box width 10px and height 10px and i should be able to insert image which is 5px into any box dynamically in C#

Comment: Your question is still not very clear, but it seems to be that what you need is just a grid of images. Is this the case? Do you need to visualize those images? Is it a WinForms application? WPF? Silverlight? Asp.Net? If it is a visualization problem, saying just that you are using C# is usually not enough.

Comment: yes a grid of images in C# windforms

Answer (score 0):

So you want to divide an image into boxes of 10x10 each, then insert another 5x5 image into any of those boxes and have the changes reflected on the original image? You can do this:

```
void AddBox(int row, int col, Image mainImage, Image otherImage) {
     using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mainImage)) {
          g.DrawImage(otherImage, col * 10, row * 10);
     }
}
```